# Find sum of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-k}2^n$?

Tags: calculus, summation

What is the solution of the above problem.

I have done the following, which I think is not the solution.

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-k}2^n$

= $\lim_{p\to -\infty} \displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{-k}2^n$

= $\lim_{p\to -\infty} [{\frac {2^{n+1} - 1} {2-1}}]_p^{-k} $

= $\lim_{p\to -\infty} [{2^{n+1} - 1}]_p^{-k}$

= $\lim_{p\to -\infty} [{2^{-k+1} - 1} -{2^{p+1} + 1} ]$

= $[{2^{-k+1} } -{2^{-\infty+1}} ]$

= ${2^{-k+1} } $

Is it correct? If not, what is the correct solution?

Comment: The calculation looks ok, though I would avoid the notation $2^{-\infty+1}$ if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it like an infinite GP:Let $i=-n$ then we have$$\sum_{i=\infty}^{k}2^{-i}=\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^i}$$ (unlike in integrals, changing the order of limits does not change the summation value: for eg. $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{3} i$ is the same as $\displaystyle\sum_{i=3}^{1} i$.)

The expression is an infinite GP with common ratio less than $1$, so we have the sum as $$S=\frac{a}{1-r}$$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio. Here,the sum turns out to be $\dfrac{\tfrac{1}{2^k}}{1-\tfrac12}=\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}=2^{1-k}.$